# MySQL - Select from another table by id, get the id by username from a different table

Tags: mysql

I have a basic table named `Players`, it contains basic data about a player like username, id, and personal data.

I have another table, for user's authentication which contains authentication data.. each field belongs to a `player_id`.

Now, I don't want to send two queries, I want to do this in one query:

How can I get authentication data (including player data) just by having player's username?
I need to select from players, get the id and select from authentication, but how would I build that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This you should use `JOIN' to get data from`players`and`authentication`

```
SELECT players.player_table_fields, authentication.authentication_table_fields  
FROM players JOIN authentication 
ON players.player_id = authentication.player_id
```